# How to include twig file from array?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

Hi how do I pass a array to a twig include?

```
{% set navbar_logo %}["{{sprinkle|raw}}/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig", "/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig"]{% endset %}

{% include navbar_logo %}
```

this results in:

```
Unable to find template "["@admin/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig", "/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig"]"
```

this works fine:

```
{% include ["{{sprinkle|raw}}/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig", "/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig"] %}
```

But i need to get it from the variable.

This also works:

```
 {% set navbar_logo %}{{sprinkle|raw}}/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig{% endset %}

{% include navbar_logo %}
```

But I need the backup incase the first one does not exist.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `{% set .. %}... {% endset %}`, Twig is treating the variable as a string

You should switch your code to this and then it works

```
{% set navbar_logo = [ sprinkle~"/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig", "/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig"] %}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
{% set navbar_logo = include(sprinkle|raw ~ '/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig') %}
```

I don't exactly know what you're trying to achieve, but a better approach would be to set this in a block of your base layout.

```
{% block navbar_logo %}
    {{ include(sprinkle|raw ~ '/components/content/navbar/navbar-logo.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Then when you later need to dump your logo, use `{{ block('navbar_logo') }}`.

More about [blocks](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/block.html)